# CakePHP wait for alert acceptance

Tags: php, function, cakephp

I have a user registration page that launches a third party script for a game, i only want this page to finish loading if the user accepts the permission (it will set a HTTP variable). I currently have it prompting for permission but is loading the page in the background, how would i go about "waiting" or "reloading" the page to re-check if this variable is set yet?

Controller function for add

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->User->IGBRequireTrust()) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Public function in Model that is called above

```
// Returns TRUE if the user trusts the site, FALSE otherwise.
    public function IGBRequireTrust()
    {
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED'] != 'yes')
        {
            echo "<script>CCPEVE.requestTrust('http://*.".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."');</script>";
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The page needs to redirect back to the index function with a session flash msg set if they do not accept the permission. I tried adding an else in where it calls the IGBRequireTrust function but it seems to always do both.

UPDATE:

AppController Function

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');

```
if($this->name == 'Users' && $this->action == 'add'){
    //die('correct controller and action');
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED'])){
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED'] != 'yes' && $this->action != 'promptEveTrusted'){
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'promptEveTrusted'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Registration is only allowed through the EVE in game browser.'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'index'));
    }
//} else {
  //  die('wrong controller and action');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are injecting javascript into the page, which will not get rendered until after all php code. Maybe try using javascript as your logic here. Or jquery would be super easy. Also, `$this->User->IGBRequireTrust()` is always returning true. put return false in your if statement

```
// Returns TRUE if the user trusts the site, FALSE otherwise.
    public function IGBRequireTrust()
    {
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED'] != 'yes')
        {
            echo "<script>CCPEVE.requestTrust('http://*.".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."');</script>";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

<script>
var eve_trusted = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED']; ?>';
var declined_eve_url = '<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>users/unauthorized';
//Might have to wait for your script injection to load so we will wait for document ready
$(function(){
    if(!eve_trusted) window.location.href = declined_eve_url;
});
</script>
```

Here I would offer you help in canceling the page load with js but, I am not sure of the order that your main script will load.

Alternatively, you could clean all of this up by putting your logic in the beforeFilter of your AppController.ctp

```
function beforeFilter(){
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED'] != 'yes' && $this->action != 'promptEveTrusted')
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'User', 'action'=>'promptEveTrusted'));
}

//USERS CONTROLLER
function promptEveTrusted(){
    //This will give the user a blank template, comment if you don't wish this
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
//views / users / prompt_eve_trusted.ctp
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
     CCPEVE.requestTrust('http://*.".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."');
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: i have tried to use the beforeFilter idea you posted above, but this just redirect every page to /Users/promptEveTrusted and then i get a too many redirects error.

Comment: Note: I have a value in the if statement to check if the current action is the action being redirected to. That should stop the redirect. You may have to play with the statement a bit.

Comment: I am trying to understand the logic and cant unfortunetly. Sorry to be a pain. if the variable is NOT set and the action is NOT promptEveTrusted then go to that action. I attempted to change this to action == 'add' as i am trying to only prompt and redirect back to the add action as once the user accepts the prompt there are other variables set that i want to autofill in the form. For all out of game browsers i will just redirect back to index with a message saying you must use in game browser. I am able to tell if they are using the in game browser using isset($_SERVER['HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED']))

Comment: I think you do understand the logic, just not the direction I was trying to point you. I was creating a new controller function with a new view just to handle the validation of HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED with promptEveTrusted function. Then, in the before filter, If the variable is not set, redirect the user to accept the request. It could be me that is misunderstanding the question. All `$this->action != 'promptEveTrusted'` is doing is preventing the redirect again once the users gets to that page.

Comment: thanks! i have it redirecting to the new function (i updated my appcontroller function above) but now because the javascript is not in the body onload tag, it is not running. How would i make the javascript run when that function is shown?

Comment: I find jquery is the best cross-browser solution for this... I will update my code with the jquery in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the page without the http variable and that would just show a message (by javascript, for example).

If the user accepts it, then, javascript will redirect him to the same page with a variable, which will then load everything you want when the variable is set.

If he doesn't accept it, it will just keep in the same page or redirect him to another one, as you prefer.